# Simplify nested case when statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-when, subquery, multiple-conditions

Below is my current SELECT CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN edition = 'STAN' AND has9 = 1 THEN '9'
WHEN edition = 'STAN' AND has8 = 1 THEN '8'
WHEN edition = 'STAN' AND has7 = 1 THEN '7' 
WHEN edition = 'STAN' AND hasOLD = 1 THEN 'OLD'
WHEN edition = 'SUI'  AND has_s9 = 1 THEN 'S9' 
WHEN edition = 'SUI'  AND has_s8 = 1 THEN 'S8' ELSE 'S7' END AS version
```

I do not always want to repeat the edition = 'xxx' condition, such as

```
CASE WHEN edition = 'STAN' AND has9 = 1 THEN '9' ELSE WHEN has8 = 1 THEN '8' ELSE WHEN has7 = '7' ELSE WHEN edition 'SUI' AND has_s9 = 1 THEN 'S9' ELSE ...
```

In Excel this is fairly easy but how can I compile that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Judging from your current SELECT CASE statement, you need to review your data model. Either has9, has8, has7 and hasOld are mutually exclusive or there is some hierarchy to them. In both cases you are better of restructuring your data model.

Comment: I agree, this was only a shortened version here as my priority was on the nested case when statement. You are right, there is some hierarchy, in full it would read like `SELECT CASE WHEN edition = 'STAN' AND has9 = 1 THEN '9' WHEN edition = 'STAN' AND has9 = 0 AND has8 = 1 Then '8' etc. ` Is that what you were referring to Patrick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN edition = 'STAN' THEN 
     CASE 
          WHEN has9 = 1 THEN '9'
          WHEN has8 = 1 THEN '8'
          WHEN has7 = 1 THEN '7'
          WHEN hasOLD = 1 THEN 'OLD'
     END
WHEN edition = 'SUI' THEN
     CASE 
          WHEN has9 = 1 THEN 'S9'
          WHEN has8 = 1 THEN 'S8'
     END
ELSE 'S7' END AS version
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest your case when.

By the way, when you make a case on a single field, you can do

```
case <field> when <value>
             when <otherValue>
```

rather then

```
 case when <field> = <value>
      when <field> = <otherValue>
```

So

```
case edition
      when 'STAN'
         case when has9 = 1 then '9'
              when has8 = 1 then '8'
              when has7 = 1 then '7'
              when hasOLD = 1 then 'OLD'
         end
     when 'SUI'
         case when has_s9 = 1 then 'S9'
              when has_s8 = 1 then 'S8'
         end
     else 'S7'
end as version
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres supports [both syntax variants for `CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE): the "simple CASE" and the "searched CASE". Use a "simple CASE". And you can also nest to mix both variants:

```sql
SELECT CASE edition 
       WHEN 'STAN' THEN 
          CASE WHEN has9 = 1 THEN '9'
               WHEN has8 = 1 THEN '8'
               WHEN has7 = 1 THEN '7' 
               WHEN hasOLD = 1 THEN 'OLD'
               -- no ELSE means ELSE NULL
          END
       WHEN 'SUI' THEN
          CASE WHEN has_s9 = 1 THEN 'S9' 
               WHEN has_s8 = 1 THEN 'S8'
          END  -- no ELSE means ELSE NULL
       ELSE 'S7'
       END AS version;
```

To carry this ***one step further*** , you can switch *constant* and *variable*. Both are just expressions and can trade places in Postgres. Maybe not as easy to read and understand, but if you want the shortest code ...

```sql
SELECT CASE edition 
       WHEN 'STAN' THEN 
          CASE 1
          WHEN has9   THEN '9'
          WHEN has8   THEN '8'
          WHEN has7   THEN '7' 
          WHEN hasOLD THEN 'OLD'
          END
       WHEN 'SUI' THEN
          CASE 1
          WHEN has_s9 THEN 'S9' 
          WHEN has_s8 THEN 'S8'
          END
       ELSE 'S7'
       END AS version;
```

Aside: The syntax for [`CASE` statements in plpgsql (the procedural language)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.6.6) is slightly different. (Different thing, really!)