# Simpify PL/pgSQL function with lots of if-else statements and JSONification

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have `PL/PgSQL` function that performs quite similar queries (the only thing that they have different is column names) and converts the output into JSON object.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_observations(kind varchar, site_id integer, var varchar) RETURNS TABLE (fc json) AS
$func$
BEGIN
    IF kind = 'raw' THEN
        IF var = 'o2_abs' THEN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(obs))) FROM (
                SELECT observation_date AS date, o2_abs AS value FROM oxygen WHERE new_id = site_id) AS obs;
        ELSIF var = 'o2_rel' THEN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(obs))) FROM (
                SELECT observation_date AS date, o2_rel AS value FROM oxygen WHERE new_id = site_id) AS obs;
        ELSIF var = 'temp' THEN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(obs))) FROM (
                SELECT observation_date AS date, t AS value FROM oxygen WHERE new_id = site_id) AS obs;
        END IF;
    ELSIF kind = 'averaged' THEN
        IF var = 'o2_abs' THEN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(obs))) FROM (
                SELECT month AS month, o2_abs AS value FROM oxygen_month_average WHERE new_id = site_id) AS obs;
        ELSIF var = 'o2_rel' THEN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(obs))) FROM (
                SELECT month AS month, o2_rel AS value FROM oxygen_month_average WHERE new_id = site_id) AS obs;
        ELSIF var = 'temp' THEN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(obs))) FROM (
                SELECT month AS month, t AS value FROM oxygen_month_average WHERE new_id = site_id) AS obs;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The body of function contains a lots of repeated code. I see several methods to improve it, but don't know if `PL/PgSQL` allows these tricks:

1. Store `obs` query result in the intermediate variable and convert it into JSON with `array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(obs)))` in the end of function.
2. Cast `var varchar` into column name definition in query in order to avoid the most of `IF`/`ELSE` statements;

PostgreSQL server version is 9.3.6.

Table schemas:

```
oxygen=# \d+ oxygen
Table "public.oxygen"
         Column          |  Type   |                      Modifiers       (...)
-------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------
 old_id                  | text    | not null
 observation_date_string | text    | not null
 t                       | real    | not null
 o2_abs                  | real    | not null
 o2_sat                  | real    |
 o2_rel                  | real    |
 observation_date        | date    |
 new_id                  | integer |
 id                      | bigint  | not null default nextval('oxygen_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "oxygen_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "oxygen_new_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (new_id) REFERENCES unique_geoms(new_id)
    "oxygen_old_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (old_id) REFERENCES location(old_id)


oxygen=# \d+ oxygen_month_average
Table "public.oxygen_month_average"
 Column |       Type       |                             Modifiers        (...)
--------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 new_id | integer          |
 month  | integer          |
 t      | double precision |
 o2_abs | double precision |
 o2_rel | double precision |
 id     | bigint           | not null default nextval('oxygen_month_average_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "oxygen_month_average_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: You can use `json_agg()` instead of `array_to_json(array_agg())`

Comment: As *always*, your version of Postgres, please. A table definition and some sample values wouldn't hurt either. One instance has  `t AS value`, the next has `temp AS value`. Is that a typo or intended?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you, that really was a typo. I've updated the post. Regarding the Postgres version, I can move to the most recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another, very efficient way to simplify most of it: a `CASE` statement:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_observations(_kind    text
                                          , _site_id int
                                          , _var     text)
  RETURNS TABLE (fc json)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   CASE _kind
   WHEN 'raw' THEN
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT json_agg(obs) FROM (
         SELECT observation_date AS date
              , CASE _var
                WHEN 'o2_abs' THEN o2_abs
                WHEN 'o2_rel' THEN o2_rel
                WHEN 'temp'   THEN t
                END AS value
         FROM   oxygen
         WHERE  new_id = _site_id
         ) AS obs;

    WHEN 'averaged' THEN
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT json_agg(obs) FROM (
         SELECT month AS month
              , CASE _var
                WHEN 'o2_abs' THEN o2_abs
                WHEN 'o2_rel' THEN o2_rel
                WHEN 'temp'   THEN t
                END AS value
         FROM   oxygen_month_average
         WHERE  new_id = _site_id
         ) AS obs;
   END CASE;
END
$func$;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nc6FlvEV)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/26d7e/1)</sub>

Still two distinct queries because those are based on different tables. To fold those, too, you would need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`, but that wouldn't get much shorter and is typically less efficient ...

Use a "simple" (or "switched") `CASE`. Note the `CASE` keyword in two distinct contexts: the outer `CASE` is a PL/pgSQL control structure, the inner [`CASE` is an SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE). Related:

- [Simplify nested case when statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823179/simplify-nested-case-when-statement/23839984#23839984)

You can simplify even further with [`json_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) like [@Igor already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252658/simpifying-the-pl-pgsql-function-with-a-lots-of-if-else-statements-and-jsonifica#comment48612577_30252658):
`array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(obs)))` -> `json_agg(obs)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [EXECUTE statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in psql to generate dynamic queries.

But it would not cache query plans so it can make each invocation slightly slower. So your code isn't that bad, regardless of code repetition.

But add error checking for invalid arguments. Otherwise you'd have very hard to find bugs if you make a typo like `avergaed` somewhere.