# Group rows with similar strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have searched a lot, but most of solutions are for concatenation option and not what I really want.

I have a table called `X` (in a Postgres database):

```
anm_id  anm_category anm_sales
1       a_dog        100
2       b_dog        50
3       c_dog        60
4       a_cat        70
5       b_cat        80
6       c_cat        40
```

I want to get total sales by grouping 'a_dog', 'b_dog', 'c_dog' as dogs and 'a_cat', 'b_cat', 'c_cat' as cats.

I cannot change the data in the table as it is an external data base from which I am supposed to get information only.

How to do this using an SQL query? It does not need to be specific to Postgres.

Comment: The best solution depends on exact details. Your example may be over-simplified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `case` statement to group the animals of same categories together

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN anm_category LIKE '%dog' THEN 'Dogs' 
         WHEN anm_category LIKE '%cat' THEN 'cats' 
         ELSE 'Others' 
       END            AS Animals_category, 
       Sum(anm_sales) AS total_sales 
FROM   yourtables 
GROUP  BY CASE 
            WHEN anm_category LIKE '%dog' THEN 'Dogs' 
            WHEN anm_category LIKE '%cat' THEN 'cats' 
            ELSE 'Others' 
          END
```

Also this query should work with most of the databases.

Answer (score 1):

By using **PostgreSQL's** [**split_part()**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html)

```
select animal||'s' animal_cat,count(*) total_sales,sum(anm_sales) sales_sum from(
select split_part(anm_cat,'_',2) animal,anm_sales from x 
)t
group by animal
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fa516/8/0)

By creating [**split_str()**](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) in **MySQL**

```
select animal||'s' animal_cat,count(*) total_sales,sum(anm_sales) sales_sum from(
select split_str(anm_cat,'_',2) animal,anm_sales from x 
)t
group by animal
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be33ab/6/0)

Comment: You are missing the sum of anm_sales column, see here instead http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fa516/5 .

Answer (score 0):

You could group by a `substr` of `anm_catogery`:

```
SELECT   SUBSTR(anm_catogery, 3) || 's', COUNT(*)
FROM     x
GROUP BY anm_catogery
```

Comment: @wingedpanther indeed, how embarrassing :-( Fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: You forgot the alias name `anm_catogery` after the first column. And, who is to tell you that the '_dog' or '_cat' portion starts after the first character?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constant length of the appendix like in the example:

```
SELECT CASE right(anm_category, 3) AS animal_type  -- 3 last char
     , sum(anm_sales) AS total_sales 
FROM   x 
GROUP  BY 1;
```

- You don't need a `CASE` statement at all, but if you use one, make it a "simple" `CASE`:

  - [Simplify nested case when statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823179/simplify-nested-case-when-statement/23839984#23839984)
- Use a positional reference instead of repeating a possibly lengthy expression.

If the length varies, but there is always a single underscore like in the example:

```
SELECT split_part(anm_category, '_', 2) AS animal_type  -- word after "_"
     , sum(anm_sales) AS total_sales 
FROM   x 
GROUP  BY 1;
```