# PostgreSQL's ILIKE query with conditional filtering

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I'm writing a user search method that is supposed to search for users by their phone number, email and username. The thing is that users are allowed to hide their phone number and email.
So, if they do hide it in their privacy settings of the application then they should not be listed in the search result.

I'm using typeorm to build this search query and here's what would be my attempt to do this
if that requirement with the hiding personal info were not there:

```
const whereClause = `
        (
            "user".phone ILIKE :searchTerm
                OR "user".username ILIKE :searchTerm
                OR "user".profile_email ILIKE :searchTerm
        ) AND "user".id != :userId
        `;

const users = await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
                                       .where(whereClause, filters)
                                       .leftJoinAndSelect('user.subscription', 'subscription')
                                       .leftJoinAndSelect('user.profilePrivacyPermissions', 'perms')
                                       .limit(ESearchResponseLimit.USERS)
                                       .getMany();
```

The profile privacy table looks as follows:

[image: profile_privacy]

Screen type 1 corresponds to phone number and 2 corresponds to email. For now we only consider two possible states: `isEverybody` and `isNobody` (that's we don't consider contacts). So, e.g., if a user decided to hide his phone number then the `isNobody` value will be equal to true, others will be set to false.

What I need is to somehow take these privacy settings into account in that search query I'm building. It should be something like this:

```
        const whereClause = `
        (
            ("user".phone ILIKE :searchTerm IF (perms.screenType = ${EScreenType.PHONE_NUMBER} AND perms.isEverybody))
                OR "user".username ILIKE :searchTerm
                OR ("user".profile_email ILIKE :searchTerm IF (perms.screenType = ${EScreenType.EMAIL} AND perms.isEverybody))
        ) AND "user".id != :userId
        `;
```

The problem is that there's no such an operator as `IF` but the idea is that I need to search by phone if it is not hidden, I need to search by email if it is not hidden either. I can't come up with even a remote idea on how to implement this in a query.

If it's possible to do with a raw query, it would be also good.

I've found out that there's the `IF` operator in PostgreSQL but I don't see how I would use it here.

EDIT:

If I search by phone when email is hidden (which means that for the email screen `perms.isEverybody = false`) the profilePrivacyPermissions field of the user object looks as follows:

```
"profilePrivacyPermissions": [
      {
        "screenType": 1,
        "isEverybody": true,
        "isContacts": false,
        "isNobody": false
      }
    ]
```

But it should look as follows:

```
    "profilePrivacyPermissions": [
      {
        "screenType": 1,
        "isEverybody": true,
        "isContacts": false,
        "isNobody": false
      },
      {
        "screenType": 2,
        "isEverybody": false,
        "isContacts": false,
        "isNobody": true
      },
      {
        "screenType": 4,
        "isEverybody": true,
        "isContacts": false,
        "isNobody": false
      },
      {
        "screenType": 5,
        "isEverybody": true,
        "isContacts": false,
        "isNobody": false
      },
      {
        "screenType": 3,
        "isEverybody": true,
        "isContacts": false,
        "isNobody": false
      }
    ]
```

I understand it happens because of the `perms` conditions in the where clause of the query.

Comment: Use boolean dummies. The optimiser will understand: eg `WHERE ( :ignore_xclause OR field ILIKE :xfield) ...` using True for :gnore_xclause this will be optimised out.

Comment: @wildplasser mmm not sure if I understood it right. Would you please write a more verbose example?

Comment: I added an answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE 1=1
AND ( True OR nm.strain = :_strain ) -- Boolean logic to short-circuit optional conditions
AND ( False OR nm.strain ILIKE :_strain_like )
...
```

---

The parametrised query:

---

```
WHERE 1=1
AND ( " . $ignore_strain . " OR nm.strain = :_strain ) -- Boolean logic to short-circuit optional conditions
AND ( " . $ignore_strain_like . " OR nm.strain ILIKE :_strain_like )
...
```

---

(this is PHP, but the technique is the same)

Comment: Good approach but there seems to be a little problem with it. Not sure if I can explain it in short, I will try. I need this search to find users by email and phone simultaneously (so it can't be always AND, the 2nd line should start with OR), that's to say if email is g123@mail.com and phone is 123, and the searchTerm is 123, the user should appear in the search result regardless of whether their phone or email is hidden. Now when this is the case: -->

Comment: `const whereClause = ` 1=1 AND (true OR "user".phone ILIKE :searchTerm) OR (false OR "user".profile_email ILIKE :searchTerm) AND "user".id != :userId `;` The search by email won't be fired off cos the left part (before OR) will always be true.

Comment: Is there some work around for this? I seem to be a bit too slow at the moment to come up with something reasonable...

Comment: In your particular case, you could just swap the ANDs and ORs: `OR ( :want_phone_number AND phone_number LIKE :the_number)`

Answer (score 1):

**`IF`** is not part of SQL in Postgres (nor standard SQL). It's part of the procedural elements added by [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html).

In **plain SQL**, just use boolean logic with **`AND`**:

```
    const whereClause = `
    (   perms.isEverybody AND 
       (perms.screenType = ${EScreenType.PHONE_NUMBER} AND "user".phone ILIKE :searchTerm
     OR perms.screenType = ${EScreenType.EMAIL}        AND "user".profile_email ILIKE :searchTerm)
     OR "user".username ILIKE :searchTerm
    ) AND "user".id != :userId
    `;
```

Or use SQL [**`CASE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE), may be easier to understand (logically equivalent):

```
    const whereClause = `
    (CASE WHEN perms.isEverybody THEN
        CASE perms.screenType
           WHEN ${EScreenType.PHONE_NUMBER} THEN "user".phone ILIKE :searchTerm
           WHEN ${EScreenType.EMAIL}        THEN "user".profile_email ILIKE :searchTerm
        END
     END
     OR "user".username ILIKE :searchTerm
    ) AND "user".id != :userId
    `;
```

The subtle difference: Only the first branch where the `WHEN` clause evaluates to `true` is executed. Other branches of the same `CASE` statement are not even entered. (So no exception is raised if something illegal is lurking there.)

I left out the `ELSE` clause, which defaults to `NULL` in SQL - and that is equivalent to `false` in the `WHERE` clause, where only `true` qualifies.

Note, I am using two different syntax variants of `CASE` ("simple" and "searched".) See:

- [Simplify nested case when statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823179/simplify-nested-case-when-statement/23839984#23839984)
- [Display column name with max value between several columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067014/display-column-name-with-max-value-between-several-columns/27071163#27071163)

Note also, there is a procedural [`CASE` in PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS), which serves a similar purpose, but is strictly distinct from [SQL `CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE).

Comment: mmm I looked at the query but I don't get how it's supposed to work, for example, there should also be the second condition addressing the email: `perms.screenType = ${EScreenType.EMAIL} AND perms.isEverybody`. As far as I can see, using `AND` here just selects those users for which the specified conditions resolve to true, but I need those conditions to check whether the `ILIKE` queries need to be executed or not. And if the conditions resolve to true, then the result should be a list of whole user objects containing all its fields. Seems like this query does not do this.

Comment: or I don't understand something.

Comment: `then the result should be a list of whole user objects containing all its fields`: The `WHERE` clause has no effect on which columns are returned. It decides whether the row is included in the result or not. The `SELECT` list decides *what* of the row is returned.

Comment: @Albert: I had misread `EScreenType.EMAIL` as `EScreenType.PHONE_NUMBER` and collapsed both together by mistake. It should work now.

Comment: Oh yeah I see, thank you for the detailed answer, yesterday I realised that logic but there seems to be still a problem there, I described it in the EDIT. Would you please have a look at it?

Comment: It has to do with the join-select operator in the typeorm queryBuilder I mean this one, `.leftJoinAndSelect('user.profilePrivacyPermissions', 'perms')`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the new question you added.